# Changing lineCap and lineJoin prior to drawing a rectangle doesn't do anything?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have this code:

```
context.lineWidth = 10;

context.lineCap = "square";
context.lineJoin = "square";

context.strokeRect(x, y, w, h);
```

`lineWidth` seems to be working just fine but changing `lineCap` and `lineJoin` doesn't do anything. The rectangle is still rounded from earlier when I set the `lineCap` and `lineJoin` to `"round"`. Does anyone know why this is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its because you need to use `miter` for `lineJoin` since `square` isn't a valid value.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/MAUd8/)**

> The lineJoin attribute defines the type of corners that UAs will place where two lines meet. The three valid values are bevel, round, and miter.

**[W3 reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/2dcontext/#dom-context-2d-linejoin)**

Also if you're just doing rects, you don't need `lineCap`